# Two ListViews in one Activity == two adapters or one adapter?

Tags: android, listview, listview-adapter

Not sure how to expand on the title.

If I have two ListViews in the same activity (for instance using the ViewPager object in the compat pack or similar) is it "standard practice" to have two separate adapters or one adapter with embedded `if` statements?

In my opinion it will be more work but much more maintainable and useful to use two separate adapters, especially as there are going to be two different data sources and different list view row layouts.

What do you do and why? Which one would be better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is unclear if by "adapters" you mean "adapter classes" or "adapter instances".

Unless you are writing the `Adapter` totally from scratch, you have no guarantees that an `Adapter` is stateless. Hence, it is safest to use separate `Adapter` instances.

If you really mean "adapter classes", given your description, I would think it might even be *easier* to have separate classes, let alone more maintainable, for your scenario. I'd definitely use two separate `Adapter` classes. If there's enough common code to make it worthwhile, use inheritance.

Comment: I agree you should accept the answer. Having 1 instance of an adapter is more work and less "stable" Many things can go wrong. 1 thing i can think of is that the 2 listviews even on a different screen can scroll simultaneously.. things can go messy

Comment: yes, sorry I meant physical adapter classes. Sorry that wasn't very clear. Thank you for your answer. I didn't know if it was one adapter class per list view or one adapter class for all the list views. Thanks for your help.